# Is it possible to have static ip in a network and dynamic one in other?

Tags: networking, wifi

I know how to set an static ip. I have 2 configured networks in wpa-supplicant. An i use to use the same static ip in both networks (2 different networks but same wifi range).

The problem is that my static ip is 10.92.x.x and my mobile network i in 192.168.x.x so is not possible to use that. What i want is that when i have that problem i can add a network in wpa_supplicant (My host is under windows 10 and from windows i can't access to /boot), that is the only folder that i can see from windows and then use the dhcp to get ip. Later on i will use ip scanner angry ip or even i will check my phone to check it the ip out.

The question is simple i want to have different networks with different static ips.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is far too vague; [How to set up networking/WiFi](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697) explains most options. The real issue is **WHY** you want to use static IP.

Comment: I don't underastan why you don't understand why should i have an static ip in my pi. I am working in a project that involves rfid, raspberry and lamp stack, so i have a web server in my rasp so i need an static ip. The problem is that those days i am havinf some network problems and i want to use my phone as an ap to share my mobile connection with my rasp

Comment: but the problem is that my static ip is 10.92.x.x and my mobile network i in 192.168.x.x so is not possible to use that. What i want is that when i have that problem i can add a network in wpa_supplicant (My host is under windows 10 and from windows i can't access to /boot), that is the only folder that i can see from windows and then use the dhcp to get ip. Later on i will use ip scanner angry ip or even i will check my phone to check it the ip out. @Milliways

Comment: you can bind each interface to one network, this is not RPi specific

Comment: What are you asking? _"Is it possible to have static ip in a network and dynamic one in other?"_ or _"The question is simple i want to have different networks with different static ips."_